# When did they start requiring holotypes for species description?

Tags: terminology, biology, taxonomy

I know they weren't required in the early 1800s but obviously they are now so just wondering when this started being required and/or who coined holotype. Internet research yielded no good answers.

Comment: Presumably botany and zoology receive slightly different answers. I would assume the foundation dates of the bodies that publish the ICN and ICZN are possible answers.  As I understand it, use of type specimens was widely practiced and recommended from even before Linaeus; maybe in the 19th century there was a desire to codify the practice. It's not clear if you are asking when codification started or when the practice itself started.

Comment: either is fine, i'm just trying to get a better understanding of whether i can expect there to be a type specimen based on the year of publication

Comment: According to https://www.iapt-taxon.org/historic/index.htm , the first edition of the ICN dates to 1867.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Botanical_Congress , which says this was at the 4th meeting of the IBC, in Paris in 1867.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as botany is concerned, the concept of type specimen and obligation of using one was [introduced](https://www.iapt-taxon.org/historic/history.htm) in the 1935 version of the code (the so-called [Cambridge Rules](https://www.iapt-taxon.org/historic/1935.htm)).

For zoology, surprisingly, it is only compulsory to explicitely name a name-bearing specimen [since 1999](https://code.iczn.org/introduction/#historical-background), when the 4th (and current) edition of the ICZN code was published.

The term 'holotype' though (and the concept of typification) is older. The earliest occurrence I can find is in this short communication in the journal *Science* from 1897: [What is a type in Natural History?](https://www.science.org/doi/pdf/10.1126/science.5.121.636) by Charles Schuchert.